# Matplotlib digit grouping (decimal separator)

Tags: python, data-visualization, matplotlib

Basically, when generating plots with matplotlib, The scale on the y-axis goes into the millions.  How do I turn on digit grouping (i.e. so that 1000000 displays as 1,000,000) or turn on the decimal separator?

Comment: You can do it like this: http://tiku.io/questions/1009459/how-to-format-axis-number-format-to-thousands-with-a-comma-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in function to do this. (That's what i thought after i read your Q; i just checked and couldn't find one in the Documentation).

In any event, it's easy to roll your own.

(Below is a complete example--ie, it will generate an mpl plot with one axis having commified tick labels--although five lines of code are all you need to create custom tick labels--three (including import statement) for the function used to create the custom labels, and two lines to create the new labels and place them on the specified axis.)

```
# first code a function to generate the axis labels you want 
# ie, turn numbers greater than 1000 into commified strings (12549 => 12,549)

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
fnx = lambda x : locale.format("%d", x, grouping=True)

from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT
import numpy as NP

data = NP.random.randint(15000, 85000, 50).reshape(25, 2)
x, y = data[:,0], data[:,1]

fig = PLT.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x, y, "ro")
default_xtick = range(20000, 100000, 10000)

# these two lines are the crux:
# create the custom tick labels
new_xtick = map(fnx, default_xtick)
# set those labels on the axis
ax1.set_xticklabels(new_xtick)

PLT.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't to use the [answer posted by doug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566805/1669975) because the command `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')` raised an error in my WSL environment due to the unsupported locale.

Fortunately, starting from Python 3.8, you can utilize f-strings for variable formatting, including digit grouping. I defined the `fnx` lambda function as `fnx = lambda x : f'{x:,}'` and the code worked as intended.

Here is the the full working code, already modified.

```
fnx = lambda x : f'{x:,}'

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(15000, 85000, 50).reshape(25, 2)
x, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x, y, "ro")
default_xtick = range(20000, 100000, 10000)

# The crucial part:
# Create custom tick labels
new_xtick = map(fnx, default_xtick)
# Set these labels on the axis
ax1.set_xticklabels(new_xtick)

plt.show()
```

Note that the Python libraries *matplotlib* and *numpy* must be installed for this code to run.